# ¿Por qué puede ser que una variable de tipo Double no me tome los double que me ingresa el usuario? C# WindowsForms

Tags: c#

Mi problema se da cuando el usuario me ingresa por ejemplo 14.9 y mi variable la toma como 149. Mi variable es un double.

```
private void btn_suma_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Convert.ToDouble(txt_Resultado.Text) != 0)
    {                
        Numero1 = Convert.ToDouble(txt_Resultado.Text);
        operacion = '+';
        txt_Resultado.Text = "0";   
    }   
}
```

He depurado el código y en txtResultado.Text llega el valor 14.9 pero al quererlo guardar en Numero1 ya me lo guarda como 149.

Si alguien me puede decir cual sería el error le agradezco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para eso debes tener en cuenta el **tipo de cultura**, hay culturas como la estadounidense por ejemplo que utilizan la coma como separador de miles, y no como separador decimal, por lo que **14,9** será **149**. Por otra parte en la cultura española ocurre lo opuesto, la coma se utiliza como separador decimal. Teniendo esto en cuenta deberías preguntar en tu código si el número contiene un punto o una coma, y en dependencia del resultado obtenido usarías el **tipo de cultura** correspondiente:

```
CultureInfo culture = (txt_Resultado.Contains('.')) ? 
                       new CultureInfo("en-US") :
                       new CultureInfo("es-ES");

double resultado = double.Parse(txt_Resultado.Text, culture);
```

Para usar la **clase CultureInfo** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Globalization;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré la solución , cuando en mi calculadora quería capturar el . para que el usuario me ingresara un decimal , al momento de capturar ese valor en una variable no lo tomaba en cuenta.Lo único que hice fue sustituir el punto por la coma.
[image]